# Datetime for Embedded kernel bootstrap without RTC

Tags: linux-kernel

Wondering kernel how to determine datetime in case of no-RTC.
In my case, I noticed the datetime always set to kernel/SDK compiling time stamp(eg 2023-02-27). not 1970-01-01.
I guest

1. it is something from .config or variable set to vmlinux.
2. My DUT read/set from peripheral to set/initail datetime.

Regards
Peter

Comment: If you are using systemd, it willset the date to its build time

Comment: @Alexandre Belloni
Thanks your feedback. as below in my case.
If _systemd_ initial datetime. It is possible set to datetime on system such as _/etc/dateime_  <br/>

<pre>
    / # timedatectl
               Local time: Mon 2023-02-27 08:05:30 UTC
           Universal time: Mon 2023-02-27 08:05:30 UTC
                 RTC time: Thu 1970-01-01 00:01:47
                Time zone: n/a (UTC, +0000)System clock synchronized: no
              NTP service: n/a
          RTC in local TZ: no
</pre>

Comment: I'm not sure if this is want you want but you can use systemd.clock_usec= on the kernel commande line to get systemd to set a specific system time at boot

Comment: you can also touch /usr/lib/clock-epoch and its last modification time will be used to set the system time